# Which is better tool for Blackberry application development?

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, java-me

Which gui development option gives a optimized and faster gui for Blackberry applications?
BB tools,J2ME tools,or any other UI toolkit like LWUIT ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The BlackBerry UI classes, without a doubt.  You get access to all the BlackBerry specific UI stuff - the BB keycodes, special keys, events, better control over your app's menus, touch screen stuff for the Storm, integration with all the components on the BlackBerry (browser, maps, homescreen icons).  Better application life cycle support, including running in the background.

You may be tempted to use the J2ME classes or LWUIT if you're very interested in porting to another J2ME platform but trust me you'll kick yourself for it later.  If portability is a concern, better to separate the more platform-independent parts of your app (business logic, networking) into separate packages and build two UIs.  Also if you're like everyone else you'll want to port to iPhone before any other J2ME platforms anyway :)

Edit: Remembered I also wrote a [blog post](http://www.thinkingblackberry.com/archives/140) about this a while back - lots of the same info, but some more details that might help

Comment: Good advice re: separate UIs, LWUIT performance is terrible on the BlackBerry anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I am currently dealing with this issue, i have an app targeted for J2ME using LWUIT and ported LWUIT to blackberry, the peformance is not encouraging, i think seperating business logic is the way to go. Now looking into RIM UI's.